# How to disconnect a Rblpapi::blpConnect()

Tags: r, rblpapi

if I called a `con = Rblpapi::blpConnect()` and then removed the `con` variable, or if I just called `Rblpapi::blpConnect()` without assigning to a variable, then the connection to the Bloomberg is established and remains open even if `con` is removed. Even still, when `blpDisconnect(con)` the connection remains open.

I would like to be able switch from a local Bloomberg to BPIPE and vice versa.

Comment: That should work.  If you look closely at the function signatures, they _do_ allow to supply a connection object.  They just don't force you to on each call by caching the default one.

Comment: so the `defaultConnection` is established only after the first call to `blpConnect()`. But then why isn't it deleted after using `blpDisconnect(con)`?